# SQL Unpivot / Coalesce multiple columns into one column based on values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to unpivot / coalesce multiple columns into one value, based on values in the target columns.

Given the following sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE SourceData (
    Id INT
   ,Column1Text VARCHAR(10)
   ,Column1Value INT
   ,Column2Text VARCHAR(10)
   ,Column2Value INT
   ,Column3Text VARCHAR(10)
   ,Column3Value INT
)

INSERT INTO SourceData
SELECT 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL UNION 
SELECT 2, 'Text', 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL UNION
SELECT 3, 'Text', 2, 'Text 2', 1, NULL, NULL UNION
SELECT 4, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL
```

I am trying to produce the following result set:

```
Id          ColumnText
----------- ----------
1           NULL
2           Text
3           Text 2
4           NULL
```

Where ColumnXText column values become one "ColumnText" value per row, based on the following criteria:

1. If all ColumnX columns are NULL, then ColumnText = NULL
2. If a ColumnXValue value is "1" and the ColumnXText IS NULL, then
   ColumnText = NULL
3. If a ColumnXValue value is "1" and the ColumnXText IS NOT NULL, then
   ColumnText = ColumnXText.

There are no records with more than one ColumnXValue of "1".

What I'd tried is in this SQL Fiddle @ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f2e18/2

I'd tried (shown in SQL fiddle):
Unpivioting with CROSS / OUTER APPLY. I fell down on this approach because I was not able to get WHERE conditions to produce the expected results.

I'd also tried using UNPIVOT, but had no luck.

I was thinking of a brute-force approach that did not seem to be correct. The real source table has 44MM rows. I do not control the schema of the source table.

Please let me know if there's a simpler approach than a brute-force tangle of CASE WHENs. Thank you.

Comment: +1 for a well formatted and explained question. Unfortunately we don't see that very often this days... I'll take a look at your query shortly

Comment: Do you always have 6 columns (3 pairs of text/value) or is it unknown number?

Comment: @NenadZivkovic It is a fixed number, and always existing in pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is much mileage in trying to be too clever with this

```
SELECT 
  Id, 
  CASE 
   WHEN COLUMN1VALUE = 1 THEN COLUMN1TEXT
   WHEN COLUMN2VALUE = 1 THEN COLUMN2TEXT
   WHEN COLUMN3VALUE = 1 THEN COLUMN3TEXT
  End as ColumnText
From
  Sourcedata
```

I did have them in 321 order, but considered that the right answer might be hit sooner if the checking is done in 123 order instead (fewer checks, if there are 44million rows, might be significant)

Comment: Thank you. I was not seeing this simple of an answer as what you all had provided with a simple CASE WHEN.

Answer (score 2):

Considering you have 44 million rows, you really don't want to experiment to much to join table on itself with apply or something like that. You need just go through it once, and that's best with simple CASE, what you call "brute-force" approach:

```
SELECT 
Id
, CASE WHEN Column1Value = 1 THEN Column1Text
       WHEN Column2Value = 1 THEN Column2Text
       WHEN Column3Value = 1 THEN Column3Text
  END AS ColumnText 
FROM SourceData
```

But, if you really want to get fancy and write something without case, you could use UNION to merge different columns into one, and then join on it:

```
wITH CTE_Union AS 
(
    SELECT Id, Column1Text AS ColumnText, Column1Value AS ColumnValue 
    FROM SourceData
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Id, Column2Text, Column2Value FROM SourceData
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Id, Column3Text, Column3Value FROM SourceData
)
SELECT s.Id, u.ColumnText
FROM SourceData s
LEFT JOIN CTE_Union u ON s.Id = u.id and u.ColumnValue = 1
```

But I guarantee first approach will outperform this by a margin of 4 to 1

Comment: @CaiusJard Although we don't know if there are maybe usable indexes on some columns like ColumnXValue, that could be used with different approach

Comment: I'm sorry. By brute-force, I'd meant a real tangled CASE statement because I wasn't seeing a simple, 3 line.. For some reason I was thinking 3*3 which for my case would have been 7*7!

Comment: @d-sect you could count the number of occurrences of 1 in each column, and then arrange your case when's in descending order of count. It may provide a slight performance advantage over the set because the answer will be found faster in most cases..

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use a case expression, then you can use another `outer apply()` on a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) (or subquery/derived table) of your original unpivot with `outer apply()`:

```
;with cte as (
select s.Id, oa.ColumnText, oa.ColumnValue
from sourcedata s
  outer apply (values
    (s.Column1Text, s.Column1Value)
  , (s.Column2Text, s.Column2Value) 
  , (s.Column3Text, s.Column3Value) 
  ) oa (ColumnText, ColumnValue)
)
select s.Id, x.ColumnText
from sourcedata s
  outer apply (
      select top 1 cte.ColumnText
      from cte
      where cte.Id = s.Id
        and cte.ColumnValue = 1
    ) x
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/TMBR41346

returns:

```
+----+------------+
| Id | ColumnText |
+----+------------+
|  1 | NULL       |
|  2 | Text       |
|  3 | Text 2     |
|  4 | NULL       |
+----+------------+
```

Comment: How dya reckon that will perform given the size of the dataset?

Comment: @CaiusJard it's two table scans, so it will be be faster then that union with 4 scans, but still not as fast as Case with one scan

Comment: It's not that I didn't want a CASE WHEN, it was that I did not see a solution without many cases, etc. I was thinking of too many permutations.

Comment: @D-Sect I understand, but I will leave this answer in case it helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the first non-null text value in order. It seems as if this is what you are trying to accomplish.

```
select ID, Coalesce(Column3Text,Column2Text,Column1Text) ColumnText
from SourceData
```

Comment: This only works if you can guarantee that the ColumnXValues decrement from left to right so the rightmost text is value 1. Example: `5,'textrigt',1,'textwrong',2...` It also gives a bad result for rows where there is a columntext associated with 2, but not with value 1. Example: `5,'text wrong',2,null,1,null,null`.. it will select "textwrong" when it should select null